# Some questions about Wind Belt mechanics

Tags: orcs-must-die

I have two questions about Wind Belt:

- Does its wind blast damage the orcs?
- If I use its power to push orcs inside water, does it count towards the killing combo multiplier?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes it does damage orcs. Although it's not a whole lot, as you can see from the image below.

   [image]
2. Yes it will count towards the combo, note that it might actually take 1-2 seconds before the kill happens, after the orc(s) have landed in the water. So as always with this game, timing is key.